# Why does it invoke N+1 queries?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have a quite complex criteria query running with JPA (Hibernate 4.x as provider). I'm trying to improve performances, because actually I have a N+1 query problem. The code looks like this:

```
    @Override
public SearchResult<EntityA> findByAnyCritere(SomeCriteria critere, Integer page, Integer pageSize, String... orderBys) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();

    // count all entities
    Long unfilteredCount = countAll();

    // count filtered entities
    Long count = unfilteredCount;

    CriteriaQuery<EntityA> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(EntityA.class);
    Root<EntityA> from = criteriaQuery.from(getEntityClass());
    Join<EntityA, EntityB> joinB = from.join("entityB", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<EntityB, EntityC> joinC = joinB.join("entityC", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<EntityB, EntityD> joinD = joinB.join("entityD", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<EntityD, EntityE> joinE = joinD.join("entityE", JoinType.LEFT);

    Predicate predicate = builder.equal(from.<EntityF> get("entityF").<Long> get("id"), critere.getSomeId());
    Predicate predicateKeyword = filterLookupByValue(critere.getAnyCriteria(), builder, criteriaQuery, LookupType.TEXT_KEYWORD, keywordJoin);
    Predicate predicateNumberText = filterNumber(critere, builder, textJoin, false);

    Subquery<Long> subqueryLibelle = filterLibelle(critere.getAnyCriteria(), builder, criteriaQuery, from);

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(critere.getAnyCriteria())) {
        criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(predicate,
                builder.or(predicateKeyword, predicateNumberText, builder.exists(subqueryLibelle))));
    } else {
        criteriaQuery.where(builder.and(predicate));
    }

    criteriaQuery.select(from);

    count = JpaUtils.count(getEntityManager(), criteriaQuery);

    addSortingInstructionsIfNeeded(builder, criteriaQuery, from, orderBys);

    TypedQuery<EntityA> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    addPaginationRestrictionIfNeeded(typedQuery, page, pageSize);

    List<EntityA> entities = typedQuery.getResultList();
    LOG.debug("found {} entities", entities.size());

    return toSearchResult(unfilteredCount, count, entities, page, pageSize);
}
```

I'm trying to understand why I have a lot of queries run. For example, if I load page 2 with a size of 10 items, I can see Hibernate running first a query like that:

```
select * from ( 
  select inner2_.*, rownumber() over(order by order of inner2_) as rownumber_ from ( 
  select 
    <<fields>> 
  from 
    EntityA versionelk0_ 
    left outer join EntityB textversio1_ on versionelk0_.ID_TEXT_VERSION=textversio1_.ID 
    left outer join EntityC textentity2_ on textversio1_.ID_TEXT=textentity2_.ID 
    left outer join EntityD textdefini3_ on textversio1_.ID_TEXT_DEFINITION=textdefini3_.ID 
    left outer join EntityE lookupenti4_ on textdefini3_.ID_LOOKUP_KEYWORD=lookupenti4_.ID, 
    EntityF textentity6_ 
  where 
      textversio1_.ID_TEXT=textentity6_.ID and versionelk0_.ID_VERSION_ELKAT=41 
  order by textentity6_.NUMBER asc 
      fetch first 20 rows only 
  ) as inner2_ 
) as inner1_ 
where rownumber_ > 10 order by rownumber_
```

... which seems to fetch the ids to loads.

BUT after that, I can see 10 queries are launched, each to load one entity with its id.

I would prefer to have only 2 queries run, the 1st staying as it is, but the second with a SQL snippet like "WHERE ID in (<>)"

Does somebody have an explaination (or better, a solution)?

EDIT : relevant mappings (renamed for confidentiality)

```
@Entity
public class EntityA extends AbstractVersionedEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TEXT_VERSION")
    private EntityB entityB;

[...]
}

@Entity
public class EntityB extends AbstractVersionedEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TEXT")
    private EntityC entityC;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TEXT_DEFINITION")
    private EntityD definition;

[...]
}

@Entity
public class EntityC extends AbstractVersionedEntity<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER")
    private String number;

[...]
}

@Entity
public class EntityD extends AbstractVersionedEntity<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_LOOKUP_CHAPTER")
    private EntityE chapter;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_LOOKUP_CATEGORY")
    private EntityE category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_LOOKUP_KEYWORD")
    private EntityE keyword;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_LOOKUP_RECIPIENT")
    private EntityE recipient;

[...]
}

@Entity
public class EntityE extends AbstractVersionedEntity<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "KEY")
    private String key;

    @Column(name = "INDEX")
    private Integer index;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private Boolean active = Boolean.TRUE;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_LOOKUPTYPE")
    private EntityF type;

[...]
}
```

The class AbstractVersionedEntity only provides support for a @Version number, default implementation for equals/hashCode/toString and generic primary key management ( in my examples)

Most relations are lazy loaded, but my problem is not that properties are lazy loaded, but that I get 10 queries to load 10 "root" entities.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant mappings.

Comment: It happens because on an other part of your code you read your SearchResult<> and one of the @OneToMany of your Entity is lazy initialized.

Comment: No it's not, because in debug, I can see every queries are launch at the line "typedQuery.getResultList()" - it's not a lazy loading issue, it is the getResultList which triggers 10 queries instead of only 2

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what causes this behavior without any mappings. If you have a One-To-Many Collection in your entity A, try using the @BatchSize annotation like

```
@BatchSize(size = 10)
@OneToMany
private Set<EntityB> items = new HashSet<>();
```

With this annotation Hibernate will fetch the content of the collection in batches specified with size attribute, meaning Entity A will be fetched with one Select statement and the collection entries will be fetched with one Select statement with a IN clause containing at most 10 ids.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/BatchSize.html

Answer (score 0):

I was misunderstanding which entity was queried with N queries. In fact, it is a relation from my root entity, so my whole post is pointless... Please ignore it. Thank you